# Network Request Failed Error React Native, using Flask Python as BackEnd

Tags: react-redux, fetch, react-native, fetch-api

Using postman the backend seems to be getting the correct data back but when I throw it into a fetch the components are not re-rendering the state and also giving me a yellow error, of Network Request Failed.
The backend is made of Flask Python, and the FrontEnd is using Expo CLI with an android emulator, I looked up previous issues and found some saying the emulator and the machine are not connected, I fixed that issue by doing a remote/local ip ex: 192.168.1.... but it's still returning a network request failed.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../src/actions";
import EarningsBar from "./EarningsBar";

const DayCalendar = (props) => {
  const [isLoaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    props.loadStock("daily");
    if (Object.keys(props.dailyStocks).length > 0) {
      setisLoaded(true);
      console.log(props.dailyStocks);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
      {isLoaded === true &&
        props.dailyStocks.time.map(
          ({ companyshortname, epsactual, epsestimate, ticker }, index) => {
            return (
              <EarningsBar
                key={index}
                companyName={companyshortname}
                companyAbbrev={ticker}
                companyEPS={epsestimate}
                companyRev={"$3.28"}
                companyActualEPS={epsactual}
                companyActualRES={"$5.66"}
                companyGrowthEPS={"103.3%"}
                companyGrowthRev={"83.8%"}
                arrow={"good"}
              />
            );
          }
        )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    dailyStocks: state.calendar.daily,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DayCalendar);
```

This is the day calendar Component
Here is the action function

```
export const loadStock = (stock) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    try {
      fetch(`http://192.168.1.13:3000/${stock}stock`)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          dispatch({ type: "LOAD_STOCKS", payload: { stock, data } });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

My reducer states/and switch cases

```
export const initialLoginState = {
  users: [],
  searchedStocks: [],
  calendar: {
    daily: [],
    weekly: [],
    monthly: [],
  },
  stocks: [],
  searchTerm: null,
  isLoading: true,
  user_id: null,
  username: null,
  password: null,
  confirmPassword: null,
  email: null,
  birthdate: null,
  question: null,
  answer: null,
  userToken: null,
  isValidUser: true,
  isValidPassword: true,
};

export default (prevState = initialLoginState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case "LOAD_STOCKS":
      return {
        ...prevState,
        calendar: {
          [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value,
        },
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...prevState,
      };
   }
};
```

If you would like to see the full repo I have linked it down below. I have been trying to figure out the issue for quite some time now and I just need a new perspective on it, thank you so much for your time.
https://github.com/JayPankajPatel/EarningsWhisper

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using the yahoo earnings api call for the earnings calendar if you would like to remake the backend using python that is the api we are using.

Answer (score -1):

Open CMD and run ipconfig, then copy your ip address there

In your flask code, let say app.py

Change app.run() to

app.run(host=your ip address)